# How to semantically differentiate all that is called "projections"?

Tags: coordinate-system

I'm a beginner GIS student and I was always wondering why so many different things seem to be called **Projections**.

E.g.:

- (orthographic, stereographic, gnomonic) Projection, but also
- (azimuthal, conical, cylindrical) Projection

These sets represent different things, and IMO the first makes more sense to be called a projection, since it’s about projecting the imagined light rays in a specific way.

Is the second set actually called something like *“projection planes”*?

I've come across a lot of sources that name both sets simply *“projections”*.

Wikipedia's [list of map projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections) sorts them as *Types* and *Properties* respectively, but I've never heard those terms in the wild.

Is it correct to call an azimuthal orthogrpahic projection an *"azimuthal type projection with orthographic properties"*?

Should they be called like that and is the reason it's not happening only common practice?

I’m really confused about that, and seek to untangle this misunderstanding regarding the proper semantics that I've had for a while!

Comment: This is more of a general geography question than a GIS one. Please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand our purpose.

Comment: Oh, alright, sorry. I looked through the Tour but wasn't aware about the technical-geographical separation. I like stackexchange pages though - is there another place where such a beginner question for someone starting out with GIS would have its place?

Comment: Maybe check the help of the [earthscience.se] Stack Exchange to see if it might be on-topic there.

Comment: @PolyGeo - Has there been a great change in policy at GIS SE? It is a very narrow and foolish view of GIS to think that *projections* are off-topic. And i'd say they're off-topic at Earth Science.

Comment: @MartinF if I thought it was off-topic here I would have voted to close it as such.

Comment: Oops, i meant to speak to @Vince on the first point.

Comment: This question is more about semantics than it is about projections.  This question, as asked, is *broad* and *opinion-based*, in addition to not being GIS-centric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The topic of map projections is both huge and important in GIS. There are many ways to categorize them and, as far as I know, the classifier called "**Type**" has no specific meaning. One could say there are various types, kinds, families, groups, etc, of projections and it wouldn't mean anything without further explanation.

When it comes to "**Properties**" of projections, however, there's a lot more agreement. That usually means "*geometric* properties" (although, in a specific context, it could mean, say, aesthetic properties). Projections can have orthomorphic (conformal), equal area, or equidistant properties and these concern objective measures of geometric distortions that take place after projecting a globe to a map. When measurement is important, those "properties" are the most important.

The "Types" you refer to as azimuthal, conical, and cylindrical are more completely called "types of *developable surfaces*" – geometrical figures that can be easily cut and made flat. The problem is, those are really only starting models because many projections are only loosely based upon them.

You mention *orthographic*. That means the projection rays are parallel, as opposed to being from a central perspective. However, classifying projections based on rays is even less useful than via developable surface because many projections don't actually have a simple "ray" analogy.

There are other means of classifying, "typing" if you like, projections: The point of contact (tangent or secant); The aspect (conventional or oblique); The number of cuts (interruptions).

Comment: Interesting! That means that the triplet including _orthographic_ and the triplet including _azimuthal_ are somewhat "equal-level" - but different - classifications for projections? And there are many more approaches. - However from what I understand _orthographic_ and _azimuthal_ are not exclusive (e.g. there can be different versions due to different combinations). Is it appropriate to think of all this as a bucket of features that can be used as building blocks for a map representation?

Comment: Yes to all four.